# How to create a function that will find all palingrams in a dictionary (including i and a)?

Tags: python

I'm currently stuck on a problem where I have to find all palingrams in a list. I made one piece of code, however it was not efficient at all and took around 3 and a half hours to finish. I needed to find something that is more time effect.

Right now I am currently stuck with this chunk of code:

```
import sys

def load(file):
    """Open a text file & turn contents into a list of lowercase strings."""
    try:
        with open(file) as in_file:
            loaded_txt = in_file.read().strip().split('\n')
            loaded_txt = [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt]
            return loaded_txt
    except IOError as e:
        print("{}\nError opening {}. Terminating program.".format(e, file),
              file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

def find_palingrams():
    pali_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        if end > 1:
            for i in range(end):
                if word[i:] == rev_word[:end-i] and rev_word[end-i:] in word_list:
                    pali_list.append((word, rev_word[end-i:]))
                if word[i:] == rev_word[end-i:] and rev_word[:end-i] in word_list:
                    pali_list.append((rev_word[end-i:], word))
    return sorted(pali_list)
```

I'm having issues with this because it does not print specific outputs that I am looking for. It is printing words, but it is excluding cases such as "aa aa", "a ba", "a baba" etc. There is something that I am not seeing that is causing single letters to not be included fully. I am aware of the end > 1, however even with an attempt to change that I am met with confusion.

Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question, but what's a palingram?

Comment: I'm surprised you aren't getting a `NameError` on `rev_word` and `end`. Is this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code?

Comment: Can you give a small sample of your file that you are reading?

Comment: Do you mean palindrome?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean Palindrome words.
An easier way to check if a word is palindrome:

```py
>>> word = "level"
>>> word == word[::-1]
True
```

You may wanna use that cleaner way, and then add the word based on the test result:

```py
if word == word[::-1]:
    # add it to the list
```

Comment: [Palingrams](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~mesterto/Unscramble/palingrams.html) are not palindromes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

However, I found the issue. Turns out I'm just stupid and spent 2 hours and found out that it was because the word[i:] was the same in both conditional statements, when it should have been word[:i]. Also the same applies with the print statement. I forgot to change some things